# Use INFORMATION_SCHEMA not supported in prepared statements, but I'm not using prepared statments?

Tags: mysql, pdo

The query:

```
$PDO->query('use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`');
```

Fails with:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2030 This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet.`

But I am not using prepared statements with `prepare()`+`execute()` for this query , I'm using the `query()` method. How do I resolve this?

**Version info**:

PHP Version: `5.5.9-1ubuntu4`

mysql  Version: `14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3`

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. What PHP version you are using? Are you using native PDO or some class extending it?

Comment: Added versions to question.

Comment: you can always use exec() as a workaround... but I'd be interested to know what caused this error...

Comment: It was a MySQL bug for older releases: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=20665

Comment: Have you tried to change PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES with PDO::setAttribute ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're attempting to use the "use" command in the PDO->query method.  The "use" command is used typically when you're using the MySQL command-line tool and it is used to select a database.

When you create your PDO, you typically specify the database you are going to be using.  Take the following example:

```
$DBH = new PDO("mssql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname, $user, $pass");
```

The four things you need to create your database handler PDO are:

- Host
- Database Name
- Username
- Password

What you're probably doing (I can't tell because you haven't listed your PDO declaration statement) is connecting to another database then attempting to perform a query to switch databases.  I don't think PDO was designed to do that.

If you want to connect to the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database, you should do it in your PDO or create another PDO.

```
$DBH = new PDO("mssql:host=$host;dbname=INFORMATION_SCHEMA, $user, $pass");
```

Hope this solves your problem.